# Will UI developing be the part of microservice?

Tags: .net-core, microservices

Let's say we are developing an application in microservice oriented style.
It has 4 services deploying through docker-compose:

1. UI (developed in angular)
2. API gateway
3. product API
4. order API

Can we say UI is part of microservices?

Comment: web (UI) is a component, not a micro-serivce. https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/tree/dev/src/Web/WebSPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI will just be static files or rendered pages served to the browser. I wouldn't say the UI itself is part of the microservices, but depending on your integration the part serving those files or pages may be.